# Does $a _n= (\cos(\pi\frac{n ^2+1}{n}))$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> Does $a _n= (\cos(\pi\frac{n ^2+1}{n}))$ converge?

*My failing attempt is:*

For all $n \in\mathbb{N} $ we can see that : $\frac{n ^2+1}{n} = 1+ \frac{1}{n}$.
Therefore, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ we get $a _n = \cos(\pi n + \frac{\pi}{n})$.

From the identity - $\cos(a+b) = \cos(a)\cos(b) - \sin(a)\sin(b)$ , we get then for all $n$:

$$a _n = \cos(\pi n)\cos( \frac{\pi}{n}) - \sin(\pi n)s\in( \frac{\pi}{n})$$

Also, I know that $\lim_{x \to 0} \sin(x) = 0 , \lim_{x \to 0} \cos(x) = 1$.
The series $b _n = \frac{\pi}{n} $ holds - $\lim_{n \to \infty} b _n = 0$ , so by Heine's definition for the limit of a function at a point, we get - $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin(b _n) = 0 , \lim_{n \to \infty} \cos(b _n) = 1$.

In addition, I know that $|\sin(\pi n) | \leq 1 $ for all $n$. And, I know a theorem that ensures under these circumstances - $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin(b _n) \sin(\pi n)= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sin(\frac{\pi}{n}) \sin(\pi n) =  0$.
(The 'circumstances' are a series which is a multiplication of a bounded series and a series whose limit is $0$).

So, if there exists $L \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \cos(\pi n) \cos(\frac{\pi}{n}) = L$ (which I think does not exist, 'because' as shown $\lim_{n \to \infty} \cos(b _n) = 1$, but this seems like nowhere near a proper explanation. Also, whether or not $L$ exists – as far as I understand – tells us nothing about the limit of $a _n$), we can say $\lim_{n \to \infty} a _n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \cos(\pi n) \cos(\frac{\pi}{n}) - \lim_{n \to \infty} \sin(\frac{\pi}{n}) \sin(\pi n) =  L - 0 = L$.

Overall, this seems like it leads nowhere.
I would very much appreciate any help.

Comment: $\cos(\pi n)=(-1)^n$

Comment: To add to above hint: $\cos (n\pi+ \theta)=(-1)^n \cos \theta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $\cos n\pi = (-1)^n$ whose sign alternates and for sufficiently large $n$, $\cos(\pi / n)$ is positive. So the sign of $a_n$ alternates therefore $a_n$ cannot converge.

Comment: here is another series which is a multiplication of $(-1) ^n$ and a series which all of it's members are positive: $c _n = (-1) ^n [\frac{1}{n}]$. If I am not mistaken, $c _n$ 's signs alternate AND it converges (to $0$, again - if I'm not wrong). Why can't $a _n$ act the same?

Comment: @EliyahuAbadi: It's because $|a_n|$ is eventually increasing. See my answer for the clue to show it.

Comment: @Eliyahu Abadi It is because $\cos \pi/n$ converges to non zero number

Answer (score 1):

You've gotten off to a good start!

The main thing to notice now is that for sufficiently large $n,$ $$a_n\approx\cos(\pi n)=\begin{cases}1 & n\text{ is even},\\-1 & n\text{ is odd}.\end{cases}$$ One helpful thing you can use to show this is the fact that $\sin(\pi n)=0$ for all integers $n.$ Another important thing to show is that $\left|\cos\frac{\pi}{n}\right|$ is monotone increasing for sufficiently large integers $n.$

Consequently, the sequence can't converge.